# backslashes of a windows path on a mac fail in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm writing an app that sends a local path (Mac) to a Wine App API that accepts Windows paths.

I can't figure out a way to convert the path to a single backslash path for my JSON file.

1.
`paa = ["Hello", "world", "again"].join("\\");`
-> `Hello\\world\\again`

2.
`paa = ["Hello", "world", "again"].join(path.sep);`
-> `Hello/world/again`

3.
`var paa = 'Hello\World\Again'`
-> `HelloWorldAgain`

4.
`var paa = 'Hello\\World\\Again'`
-> `Hello\\World\\Again`

5.
`var paa = 'Hello\World\Again'; paa.replace(/\/g, '\\')` -> `SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing /`

6.
`paa = path.win32.join('Hello', 'World', 'Again');` -> `Hello\\World\\Again`

I tried a few other options too, to no avail.

I need the following `"Hello\World\Again"`

[image]

Here is my function in NodeJS

```
function importSound(session){

  paa = ["Y:", "My", "File", "Path\\"].join("\\") //Option 1 (Not actual path for brevity)
  paa = ["Y:", "My", "File", "Path/"].join("/")   //Option 2 (Not actual path for brevity) 
  
  var newImport = {
    importOperation: "createNew",
    default: {
      importLanguage: "SFX"
    },
    imports: [
      {
        objectPath: "{6A59D4C5-5927-4C64-82AF-4A0CBFBD4C05}",
        audioFile: paa + 'intro1.wav',
        //"@Volume": 0.42
      },
      {
        objectPath: "{6A59D4C5-5927-4C64-82AF-4A0CBFBD4C05}",
        audioFile: paa + 'intro2.wav',
        //"@Volume": 0.1
      }
    ]
  }

  console.log(newImport)

  session.call('ak.wwise.core.object.import', [], newImport ).then(
    function(res) {
      console.log(res)
    },
    function (error) {
      console.log('error: ', error);
    }
  ).then(
    function() {
      connection.close();
    }
  );

}
```

Response from Option 1

```
{
  importOperation: 'createNew',
  default: { importLanguage: 'SFX' },
  imports: [
    {
      objectPath: '{6A59D4C5-5927-4C64-82AF-4A0CBFBD4C05}',
      audioFile: 'Y:\\My\\File\\Path\\intro1.wav'
    },
    {
      objectPath: '{6A59D4C5-5927-4C64-82AF-4A0CBFBD4C05}',
      audioFile: 'Y:\\My\\File\\Path\\intro2.wav'
    }
  ]
}
error:  Error {
  error: 'ak.wwise.invalid_procedure_uri',
  args: [],
  kwargs: {
    message: 'The procedure URI is unknown.',
    details: { procedureUri: 'ak.wwise.core.object.import' }
  }
}
connection closed closed {
  reason: 'wamp.error.goodbye_and_out',
  message: '',
  retry_delay: null,
  retry_count: null,
  will_retry: false
}
```

Response from option 2 is the same just with different paths
`audioFile: 'Y:/My/File/Path/intro1.wav'`

I'm absolutely sure that my files are in the right directory.

The app that I'm calling (Wwise) has a path to the Wine project listed as `Y:\Path\To\Project` so I'm assuming that I must send a path that is encoded in the same way, in order for the API to find my files.

Comment: Why does `const paa = ["Hello", "world", "again"].join("\\"); ` results in two back slashes? That's not correct, try it in your browser's console

Comment: I believe it's your terminal emulator which is printing additional backslashes, are you sure it's a nodejs specific problem?

Comment: In the browser it works, however NodeJS returns the path with `\\\`

Comment: @Normal I tried in my terminal and with iTerm, both return the path with double backslashes.

Comment: okay move on, and pass that file path to the Wine API and see if it works?

Comment: #1, #4 and #6 should all work.  You're probablyk getting confused by your terminal output which is apparently showing you the escaped version, not the actual string.  I never use the terminal for my Javascript development because it often confuses.  Write an actual small script, insert a `console.log()` in it and run that script.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt' work. That was my first thought, too. I get error: 'ak.wwise.invalid_procedure_uri',.

Comment: @jfriend00 I do have a script, which i run with `node index.js` It is supposed to build a JSON, which I have to send to an API. For some reason the API doesn't recognize the path that I'm sending. The path is different from what the API expects so I assume that's the reason why the API throws the error.

Comment: Since Windows also allows forward slahes, why don't you just use that and avoid this whole problem?

Comment: I added more details around the case. @Barmer the forward slashes suggestion doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The error message you are getting in response clearly says that the uri you are passing (`'ak.wwise.core.object.import'`) is not a valid "uri procedure" which means that this string path is very likely to be incorrect. So the fact that you are getting this error message makes me think that your problem doesn't have anything to do with the way you are passing those `audioFile` paths and the use of backslashes.
2. As someone else pointed out in a comment, you are probably getting confused by the output your terminal is giving after evaluating those statements. Try executing the following statements in the node or browser console and you'll quickly notice that your code is correctly joining the strings with one single backslash:

   ```
   > ['Y:', 'My', 'Path'].join('\\')
   'Y:\\My\\Path' // <- Don't get confused by this, this is just a visual representation of the value that your console shows for convenience
   ```

   Now, try this instead:

   ```
   > console.log(['Y:', 'My', 'Path'].join('\\'))
   Y:\My\Path // <- This is the actual value
   ```

Comment: You are right. The string path is `ak.wwise.core.audio.import`. *facepalm*